# Angular transitionTo not reloading different state after ajax request

Tags: angularjs, ajax

**Problem:**

I'm having hard time displaying data in a different state after an AJAX request has been received.

**Current state:**

I have a form in one state to edit data.

I have the second state to display edited data.

After form has been submitted, an AJAX request sends new form data to an API and store it in the database on a server. If a response from an API is a success, a transition to a different state with sent data need to be displayed.

For an AJAX request I use factory with `$resource`. I'm getting the success response from an API, after that I perform `transitionTo` to a different state like so:

```
IssuesFactory.putIssue(serializeData, function(response) {
    if (response.id) {
       $state.transitionTo('issue',  $stateParams, {reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true});
    }
});
```

After transition to a different state has been made, I'm still getting data that was before editing. After manual page refresh I get updated data.

Why `transitionTo` with parameters `reload:true` not performing refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$state.go('issue',  $stateParams, {reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true});
```

Comment: As far as understand from here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/582 `.go() ` doesn't solve the issue. And I double checked, it doesn't work in my case.